# django.db.utils.DatabaseError

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up a django model to store regions, like USA, Germany, etc. I made the region name unique for the table. I have a script that populates the database from a list and if there is a duplicate region name IntegrityError is thrown as expected but then another error happens and I can't tell why from the error message. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Model:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Populate code:

```
    try:
        Region(name=server['locale']).save()
        print 'Added region: %(locale)s' % server
    except IntegrityError:
        pass
```

I've confirmed that the IntegrityError is occuring but then I get this error which I dont expect:

```
  File "/home/daedalus/webapps/wowstatus/lib/python2.6/django/db/models/base.py", line 456, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/home/daedalus/webapps/wowstatus/lib/python2.6/django/db/models/base.py", line 549, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
  File "/home/daedalus/webapps/wowstatus/lib/python2.6/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daedalus/webapps/wowstatus/lib/python2.6/django/db/models/query.py", line 1518, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/daedalus/webapps/wowstatus/lib/python2.6/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 788, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/home/daedalus/webapps/wowstatus/lib/python2.6/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 732, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/daedalus/webapps/wowstatus/lib/python2.6/django/db/backends/util.py", line 15, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/daedalus/webapps/wowstatus/lib/python2.6/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 44, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Answer (score 12):

You should reset your db state if something fails
for example:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def Populate():
    try:
        Region(name=server['locale']).save()
        print 'Added region: %(locale)s' % server
    except IntegrityError:
        transaction.rollback()
    else:
        transaction.commit()
```

Comment: +1, it helped me fix a problem. Just a little trick: I had to commit/rollback the transaction after rendering the template.

Answer (score 3):

I get this error sometimes when accessing the database from the django shell. I fix it by closing the connection:

```
from django.db import connection
connection.close()
cur = connection.cursor()
sql = 'select distinct category from uploads_document'
cur.execute(sql)
```

after I have made an error like 'select ditsinct ..'